# Using MVC grid and creating action links from grid data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid i'm working with, in which i would like to link one column to another screen.  I want to make it so that when the user clicks the link in the grid they will be navigated to a details screen.

Currently what I have is:

```
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle:"listing-border",headerStyle:"gridhead",footerStyle:"paging",rowStyle:"td-dark",alternatingRowStyle:"td-light",
                            columns: 
                                grid.Columns(
                                    grid.Column("BatchNumber", "Batch Number", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.BatchNumber), "BatchDetails", "Batching", new { id = (string)item.BatchNumber })),
                                    grid.Column("BatchGroupItemDate", "Date"),
                                    grid.Column("BatchComment", "Comment"),
                                    grid.Column("NumberOfDocuments", "Number of Documents"),
                                    grid.Column("TotalTransfered", "Total Transfered"),
                                    grid.Column("NotTransfered", "Not Transfered")
                                ),mode:WebGridPagerModes.All)
```

The Batch Number is clickable in my view, and indeed fires the associated controller method, however, the id value being passed in is null.  Is this because it cannot remember what was in that location in the grid client side?

Comment: What's your controller method signature?

Comment: `[Authorize]
        public ActionResult BatchDetails(string id)`

Comment: when I inspect the element of the link I am getting `<a id="1092838" href="/Batching/BatchDetails?Length=8">ADO1311010425</a>`  where `1092838` is the batch number.  It doesn't seem to be building the action link correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have above

```
grid.Column("BatchNumber", "Batch Number", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.BatchNumber), "BatchDetails", "Batching", new { id = (string)item.BatchNumber }))
```

is not correct, that particular overload is taking the id as a html parameter which explains the weird string I was getting.

This is correct:

```
grid.Column("BatchNumber", "Batch Number", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.BatchNumber), "BatchDetails", "Batching", new { id = (string)item.BatchNumber }, null))
```

The "null" here is overloading the html params to null and letting the id be passed correctly.